# How to pass entity paths into methods in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form to create and add a new item to an inventory database. During creation, keywords can be added. There are several *types* of keywords, however, so they are entered in separate sections.

I would like to have a method that takes an item ID and a keyword list, puts the keywords into the correct table, and joins the item and the keywords in a join table but I don't know how to pass in the entities.

It would look roughly like this:

```
public void AttachKeywords(int itemId, List<string> keywords, ???? tableEntity, ???? joinTableEntity)
{
    // etc.
}
```

I know contexts can be passed in but how do I pass in the equivalent of something like `context.Uses` or `context.Item_Uses` so that I could do something like:

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    tableEntity.Add(keyword);
    tableEntity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went to lunch, came back, and figured it out -- mostly.

Here's what I did...

```
public void AttachKeywords(int itemId, List<string> keywords, DbSet tableEntity, DbSet joinTableEntity)
{
    // ...
    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        tableEntity.Add(keyword);
        myDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then consumed with:

```
AttachKeywords(id, uses, context.Uses, context.Item_Uses);
```

Works!